# In the New Catholic Bible, is Isiaiah 9:5 speaking about Jesus, and who is the Wonderful Counsellor?

Tags: life-of-jesus, trinity, pneumatology, isaiah

I have a question for Trinitarian Roman Catholics as to who Isaiah 9:6 (New Catholic Bible) is describing, and who the Wonderful Counsellor is.

> **Isaiah 9:5** New Catholic Bible
>
> 5 For a child has been born to us,
> a son has been given to us.
> Upon his shoulders dominion rests,
> and this is the name he has been given:
> Wonderful Counselor, Mighty God,
> Eternal Father, Prince of Peace.

I was once a Roman Catholic. But now I am Independent Evangelical and my dad is Baptist. We both believe that the Wonderful Counsellor in this verse is refering to the Holy Spirit. And that the verse on the whole identifies the true identity of the man Jesus (Yeshua).

As Roman Catholic Trinitarians what is this verse saying, and about whom is it speaking according to your own faith and belief system?

Answer (score 2):

**In the New Catholic Bible, is Isiaiah 9:5 speaking about Jesus, and who is the Wonderful Counsellor?**

In Catholic thought and tradition, the reference to the Wonderful Counsellor is no other than Jesus in his Incarnation as man.

In fact, the very verse of **Isaiah 9:1-6** is the first reading at the Midnight Mass of the Nativity of the Our Lord, Jesus Christ (Christmas Eve Mass).

> 1st Reading – Isaiah 9:1-6
>
> 1 The people who walked in darkness have seen a great light; upon those who dwelt in the land of gloom a light has shone.
>
> 2 You have brought them abundant joy and great rejoicing, as they rejoice before you as at the harvest, as people make merry when dividing spoils.
>
> 3 For the yoke that burdened them, the pole on their shoulder, and the rod of their taskmaster you have smashed, as on the day of Midian.
>
> 4 For every boot that tramped in battle, every cloak rolled in blood, will be burned as fuel for flames.
>
> 5 For a child is born to us, a son is given us; upon his shoulder dominion rests. They name him Wonder-Counselor, God-Hero, Father-Forever, Prince of Peace.
>
> 6 His dominion is vast and forever peaceful, from David’s throne, and over his kingdom, which he confirms and sustains by judgment and justice, both now and forever. The zeal of the LORD of hosts will do this!
>
> [**Christmas Eve Mass Readings, December 25 2021 – The Nativity of the Lord Mass During the Night**](https://ca.mobiversity.com/?cid=44831&pageid=5798&lang=en&creative=591968183640&network=d&placement=catholicreadings.org&keyword=&adgroup=135194649316&device=apple%2Bipad&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIionaso3l9wIVwId_BB2TYgkXEAEYASAAEgKzr_D_BwE)

Thus if the Church employs this very verse on the Feast of the Birth of Jesus in his humanity, the phrase of Wonderful Counsellor is obviously made to refer to the Jesus who is called the Christ.

Our Lord proved to be a Wonderful Counsellor many times over in the Gospels.

Comment: Thank you, Ken.